# How to generate and use a preview of a UI5 view

Tags: sapui5

On a start page I have to offer the most recent editeded versions for quick access. I have the requirement that the user not only sees the name of the document but also a mini-preview. In fact, these documents are always the same object view but with different data bound.

So I guess the question is: Is there a simple way to include a shrunk version of a view in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to convert the rendered HTML to canvas, and display that. Google uses a similar technique for generating website previews.

There are various html2canvas script which you can use, for instance https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for. I never have thought of this. tnx